# EditText imeOptions and databinding not working

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to handle imeOption actionDone in my viewmodel using databinding.

There are a couple other posts that dont give a solution that is what im looking for. I want to set this in XML with a BindingAdapter to handle the event of actionDone. I keep receiving different databinding errors following solutions to the other posts.

I really wish I could find a doc that outlines all the databinding XML syntax and why things work cause a lot of docs (including official Android ones) use a mixture of lambdas not/passing params without explanation. change it even a little bit and binding errors in gradle build.

xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@={mainViewModel.password}"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    app:onEditorActionDone="@{(view) -> mainViewModel.onEditorActionDone(view)}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordTitle" />
```

ViewModel

```
@BindingAdapter({"onEditorActionDone"})
public void onEditorActionDone(EditText view) {
    AppLog.d(TAG, "-> onEditorActionDone()");

    view.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //do login
        }
        //do nothing
    });
}
```

I have tried
  `app:onEditorActionDone="@{mainViewModel::onEditorActionDone}"`
`app:onEditorActionDone="@{(view) -> mainViewModel.onEditorActionDone()}"`
`app:onEditorActionDone="@{mainViewModel.onEditorActionDone}"`

Comment: Actually what do you trying to do?

Comment: I updated the post, sorry for the confusion. I want to handle imeOptions actionDone in my ViewModel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a custom `@BindingAdapter`. Try this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@={mainViewModel.password}"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:onEditorAction="@{(view,actionId,event) -> viewModel.onEditorAction(view,actionId,event)}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordTitle" />
```

And your view model class should implement the `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` interface:

```
public class ViewModel implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {       
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("ViewModel", "onEditorAction");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that based on another post elsewhere. I was missing implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener which cause other databinding errors during build. Thanks!